# Razor Checkbox change visibility of text fields & dropdowns

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Simple one!

I'm currently creating a huge costing web application, it contains a huge input form with loads of fields but i just want my checkbox

```
Standard: @Html.CheckBox("Standard", false)
```

To when clicked change the visibility of

1. my textfields

   input id="KID" type="text" value=@ViewBag.kammid name="kammid" />
2. & #2 my dropdownlists

   @Html.DropDownList("selectedFacing", (SelectList)ViewBag.FacingSheets)

Ive checked tons of forums but nothing seems to work, i think i need to use Jquery, but it just does nothing when i put the code at the bottom of my view.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $("#Standard").click(function () {
      var checked = $(this).attr("checked");
      if (checked) {
        $("kammid").show();
        $("kammod").hide();
        @ViewBag.test = poo;
      } else {
        $("kammod").hide();
        $("kammid").show();
        @ViewBag.test = wee;
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

**Edited Script** (also not working)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $("#Standard").click(function () {
      var checked = $(this).attr("checked");
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $("#KID").show();
        $("#KOD").hide();
      } else {
        $("#KOD").hide();
        $("#KID").show();  
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

FULL VIEW CODE IS

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication4.Models.CoreSheets>
....
@using (Html.BeginForm("Iflexcst", "Costing", FormMethod.Post))
{
  <form>
    <h2>Enter Dimensions:</h2>
    Standard: @Html.CheckBox("Standard", false)
    <br>
    Special: @Html.CheckBox("Special", false)
    <br>
    Kamm ID:<br>
    <input class="foo" id="KID" type="text" value=@ViewBag.kammid name="kammid" />
    <br> Kamm OD: <br>
    <input id="KOD" type="text" value=@ViewBag.kammod name="kammod" />
    <br>
    Spacer ID:<br>
    <input type="text" name="SpacerInnerDim" value=@ViewBag.spacerid>
    <br>
    Spacer/Facing OD:<br>
    <input type="text" name="SpacerOuterDim" value=@ViewBag.spacerod>
    <br>
    Washers OD:<br>
    <input type="text" name="WashOuterDim" value=@ViewBag.washod>
    <br>
    Isolating Washer ID:<br>
    <input type="text" name="IsoWashInnerDim" value=@ViewBag.isoid>
    <br>
    Steel Washer ID:<br>
    <input type="text" name="SteelWashInnerDim" value=@ViewBag.steelid>
    <br>
    <h2>Enter Materials:</h2>
    <br>
    Kamm Core:<br>
    @Html.DropDownList("selectedCore", (SelectList)ViewBag.CoreSheets)
    <br>
    Spacer Core:<br>
    @Html.DropDownList("selectedSpacer", (SelectList)ViewBag.SpacerSheets)
    <br>
    Kamm and Space Facing:<br>
    @Html.DropDownList("selectedFacing", (SelectList)ViewBag.FacingSheets)
    <br>
    Steel Washer Core:<br>
    @Html.DropDownList("selectedSteelCre", (SelectList)ViewBag.CoreSheets)
    <br>
    Isolating Washer Core:<br>
    Special: @Html.CheckBox("Bought in ISO washers?", false)
    @Html.DropDownList("selectedIsoCre", (SelectList)ViewBag.CoreSheets)
    <br>
    Isolating Washer Facing:<br>
    @Html.DropDownList("selectedIsoFacing", (SelectList)ViewBag.FacingSheets)
    <br>
    <h2>Washer and Sleeve Quantity and Prices:</h2>
    <br>
    Steel Washer Quantity:<br>
    <input type="text" name="SteelWashQuan" value=@ViewBag.steelq>
    <br>
    <br>
    Isolating Washer Quantity:<br>
    <input type="text" name="IsoWashQuan" value=@ViewBag.isoq>
    <br>
    <br>
    Sleeve Quantity:<br>
    <input type="text" name="SleeveQuan" value=@ViewBag.sleeveq>
    <br>
    <br>
    Sleeve Price:<br>
    <input type="text" name="SleevePrice" value=@ViewBag.sleevepr>
    <br>
    <br>
    Isolating Washer Price:<br>
    <input type="text" name="IsoPrice" value=@ViewBag.isopr>
    <br>                                      
    <br> Cost: <br>
    <input id="Text3" type="number" value=@ViewBag.result />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
}


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        $("#Standard").change(function () {
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                $(".foo").show();
            }
            else {
                $(".foo").hide();
            }
        });

    })
            </script>
```

HERE

### Enter Dimensions:

```
Standard: @Html.CheckBox("Standard", false)

<br>
Special: @Html.CheckBox("Special", false)
<br>




Kamm ID:<br>
<input class="foo" id="KID" type="text" value=@ViewBag.kammid name="kammid" />
<br> Kamm OD: <br>
<input class="foo" id="KOD" type="text" value=@ViewBag.kammod name="kammod" />

<br>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        $("#Standard").change(function () {
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                $(".foo").show();
            }
            else {
                $(".foo").hide();
            }
        });

    })
            </script>
```

edit 5 billion

```
    @model IEnumerable<WebApplication4.Models.CoreSheets>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Iflexcst";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}



@using (Html.BeginForm("Iflexcst", "Costing", FormMethod.Post))
{


        <h2>Enter Dimensions:</h2>

    <h5>
        Standard:
    </h5> @Html.CheckBox("Standard", false);

        <br>
        <h5>
            Special:
        </h5> @Html.CheckBox("Special", false);
            <br>




            <h5> ID:</h5> <br>
            <input class="foo" id="KID" type="text" value=@ViewBag.kammid name="kammid" />
            <br><h5>Kamm OD: </h5>  <br>
            <input class="foo" id="KOD" type="text" value=@ViewBag.kammod name="kammod" />

            <br>

            <h5> Spacer ID</h5><br>
            <input type="text" name="SpacerInnerDim" value=@ViewBag.spacerid>
            <br>
            <h5> Spacer/Facing OD:</h5> <br>
            <input type="text" name="SpacerOuterDim" value=@ViewBag.spacerod>
            <br>
            <h5>Washers OD: </h5>  <br>
            <input type="text" name="WashOuterDim" value=@ViewBag.washod>
            <br>
            <h5>Isolating Washer ID: </h5>  <br>
            <input type="text" name="IsoWashInnerDim" value=@ViewBag.isoid>
            <br>
            <h5>  Steel Washer ID:</h5> <br>
            <input type="text" name="SteelWashInnerDim" value=@ViewBag.steelid>
            <br>

            <h2>Enter Materials:</h2>
            <br>
            <h5> Kamm Core: </h5>  <br>
            @Html.DropDownList("selectedCore", (SelectList)ViewBag.CoreSheets);
            <br>
            <h5> Spacer Core:</h5>   <br>
            @Html.DropDownList("selectedSpacer", (SelectList)ViewBag.SpacerSheets);
            <br>
            <h5> Kamm and Space Facing: </h5>   <br>
            @Html.DropDownList("selectedFacing", (SelectList)ViewBag.FacingSheets);
            <br>
            <h5>Steel Washer Core: </h5>     <br>
            @Html.DropDownList("selectedSteelCre", (SelectList)ViewBag.CoreSheets);
            <br>
            <h5> Isolating Washer Core: </h5>  <br>
            <h5> Special:</h5>     @Html.CheckBox("Bought in ISO washers?", false);
            @Html.DropDownList("selectedIsoCre", (SelectList)ViewBag.CoreSheets);
            <br>
            <h5>Isolating Washer Facing: </h5>   <br>
            @Html.DropDownList("selectedIsoFacing", (SelectList)ViewBag.FacingSheets);
            <br>
            <h2>Washer and Sleeve Quantity and Prices:</h2>

            <br>
            <h5>  Steel Washer Quantity:</h5>  <br>
            <input type="text" name="SteelWashQuan" value=@ViewBag.steelq>
            <br>
            <br>
            <h5>  Isolating Washer Quantity:</h5>    <br>
            <input type="text" name="IsoWashQuan" value=@ViewBag.isoq>
            <br>

            <br>
            <h5> Sleeve Quantity:</h5>   <br>
            <input type="text" name="SleeveQuan" value=@ViewBag.sleeveq>
            <br>

            <br>
            <h5>  Sleeve Price:</h5>   <br>
            <input type="text" name="SleevePrice" value=@ViewBag.sleevepr>
            <br>

            <br>
            <h5> Isolating Washer Price: </h5>    <br>
            <input type="text" name="IsoPrice" value=@ViewBag.isopr>
            <br>

            <br><h5>
    Cost:
</h5> <br>
    <input id="Text3" type="number" value=@ViewBag.result />


    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />


    }

    <br><br><br><br>

    <h2>Bom Breakdown:</h2>
    <table class="table">


        <tr>
            <th>Component</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Cost</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@ViewBag.KammCore</td>
            <td>@ViewBag.KammBom</td>
            <td>@ViewBag.KammPrice</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>@ViewBag.FaceCore</td>
            <td>@ViewBag.FaceBom</td>
            <td>@ViewBag.FacePrice</td>

        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>@ViewBag.SpacerCore</td>
            <td>@ViewBag.SpacerBom</td>
            <td>@ViewBag.SpacerPrice</td>

        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>@ViewBag.SteelWashCore</td>
            <td>@ViewBag.SteelWashBom</td>
            <td>@ViewBag.SteelWashPrice</td>

        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>@ViewBag.IsoWashCore</td>
            <td>@ViewBag.IsoWashBom</td>
            <td>@ViewBag.IsoWashPrice</td>

        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>@ViewBag.IsoWashFace</td>
            <td>@ViewBag.FaceIsoBom</td>
            <td>@ViewBag.FaceIsoPrice</td>

        </tr>



    </table>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {

            $("#Standard").change(function () {
                if ($("#Standard").is(":checked")) {
                    $(".foo").show();
                    $('#KID').show();
                }
                else {
                    $(".foo").hide();
                    $('#KID').hide();
                }
            });

        })
    </script>
```

Comment: What is the question? What is your jQuery code?

Comment: How do i make it so that when the user checks the above checkbox, it updates the visibility of text fields and dropdowns.

Comment: Your textbox has `id="KID"` so its `$('#KID').show()` (or `.hide()`)

Comment: And it should be `if ($(this).is(':checked') {...` (and why are you doing both `.show()` and `.hide()`?)

Comment: Yeah i tried that, it still does nothing :*( have i got the code in the right place, i just have it at the bottom of my view?

Comment: I now have the above as my Jquery and it still does nothing! Anddd i have i have both a show and hide because its two different text boxes ?

Comment: You cannot change your question like that. Please roll back your edits, then add the new code you have tried after the original code.

Comment: And put a breakpoint on your scripts (or add `console.log()`) statements so you can debug it

Comment: Still cant get this to work! ive added my full view code, is it something todo with my form method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems to be that your if else clause in your jquery is doing the same thing.

```
 if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $("#KID").show();
    $("#KOD").hide();
  } else {
    $("#KOD").hide();
    $("#KID").show();  
  }
```

Notice that you are showing the `#KID` in if and else and hiding `#KOD` in both as well.
Simply correct this and it should work.

```
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $("#KOD").show();
    $("#KID").hide();
  } else {
    $("#KOD").hide();
    $("#KID").show();  
  }
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p6ycyreu/2/)**

You may want to do the same for the labels (the correct way) or in your case h5's so that you don't have the text on the page without the input. Check the above fiddle for an example.

Comment: Thanks for the help, the JSfiddle was of great use, however it appears my problem is elsewhere i modified mine to meet your function, for it not to work, so then i copied in the exact thing, again for it not to work? what could be causing this?

Comment: I do not understand how it cannot work to be honest. Unless your jquery isn't loaded or there is another issue. Open Firebug, go to the console tab, click on All and rerun the page. If there are errors anywhere it should be picked up here. By the way, what browser are you using and what version of jquery?

Comment: Right from the kickoff, i am using Microsoft visual studio 2013, ASP.net MVC 5, is there anything i need to install or reference to use JQuery/javascript ?

Comment: Normally know but can you verify if JQuery is loaded? Check the scripts section of the browser to verify and add [an alert](http://jsfiddle.net/p6ycyreu/4/) at the bottom of fiddle. Also do you see any errors in your console window?

Comment: righttttttttttttttttttt, okay so inserted the alert which didnt run so that means the script isnt running, but i found the error and its giving me

Uncaught reference error $ is not defined, on this line:
 $(document).ready(function () {

Comment: That means jquery is not loaded. So to fix that either add jquery to the _layout page that is being used or add it to the bundle that you are using. I would suggest first adding it to the _layout page so you can see it work. After attempt to bundle it. And again, check the scripts downloaded when you run your application (hit ctrl+f5 to get non-cached version).

Comment: thankyou my friend, 

added
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

and it instantly started working, thanks for your time, means alot